# No permitir secuencias alfabéticas y/o numéricas en password

Tags: javascript, regex

Debo validar que cuando el usuario ingrese una contraseña, ésta no contenga una secuencia alfabética (`abcd`...etc) o numérica (`1234`...etc).

Esto lo he intentado hacer mediante una expresión regular, pero no he encontrado la correcta. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Gracias antes que nada, secuencia me refiero a abcdefg...z, 0123...9. Para iniciar a determinar que es una secuencia se tomaria cada 4 caracteres ejemplo 0123, abcd, 5678, fghi

Comment: Podrías indicarnos un ejemplo de cadena válida y otro no válido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No existe una forma de hacerlo con regex, ya que un patrón ya está compilado a priori, y no puede evaluar código sobre la marcha (al menos no sin irnos a Perl o C).

La alternativa sería generar un patrón como `/abcd|bcde|cdef|`<sub><sup>...etc</sup></sub>`/i`, pero eso no tiene sentido.

Código, el viejo y conocido código, clásico e infalible:

```js
function tieneSecuenciaDeNCaracteres(texto, N) {
    let max = N || 4, //cant de caracteres en secuencia inválida (4 predet).
        length = texto.length, //largo del texto
        caracterPrevio = texto[0], //guarda el caracter de la iteración anterior
        consecutivos = 1, //para ir incrementando cuando se encuentre una secuencia
        caracterActual; //el caracter que comparamos en cada iteración
          
    //Bucle caracter por caracter (desde el 2do hasta el fin)
    for (let i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        caracterActual = texto[i];
        if (siguienteCaracter(caracterPrevio) === caracterActual) {
            //está en secuencia con el anterior
            consecutivos++;
            if (consecutivos >= max) {
                //Máximo permitido => inválido
                return texto.substr(i - max + 1, max);
            }
        } else {
            //No está en secuencia => reiniciamos
            consecutivos = 1;
        }
        caracterPrevio = caracterActual;
    }
    //Si terminó y no encontró
    return false;
}

function siguienteCaracter(c) {
    //Podría mejorarlo, pero no tenía ganas de meterme a calcular módulos
    if (c === 'z') return 'a';
    if (c === 'Z') return 'A';
    if (c === '9') return '0';
    //le sumamos 1 y devolvemos
    return String.fromCodePoint(c.codePointAt() + 1);
}


// -------------
// Pruebas
let pruebas = [
        'abc-def-ghi',
        'qponmlkjihg',
        '00001bcde10000',
        '----7890----',
        'ABCdefGHIjklMN',
        'ooooxyzaooooo',
        'abcjkl4567pqcj'
    ];
for (let prueba of pruebas) {
    console.log(prueba, "\t-->", tieneSecuenciaDeNCaracteres(prueba));
}
```

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias en efecto asi es como me referia a encontrar la secuencia de caracteres.